# force block element to fit inline-block parent instead of inline-block content

Tags: html, css

## Problem

In my setup I have a root element that contains several fixed-width children and several variable children. By "fixed-width" I mean that the element's width isn't determined by anything that happens outside the element. (They have to be inline-block and must not be inline though.) The root element should fit the widest fixed-width child and all the variable children should fit the root element. However the variable-width children can contain inline-blocks that overflow its parent. And that is what's causing me headaches. Because as long as the children of the variable elements stay small enough my setup works. But when they get bigger than their parents' client width the variable elements suddenly start fitting their children instead of their parent and I'm not sure how to force them not to.

## Example

Consider the simplified example below. In this case the white box is a fixed-width element, the green box the root element and the yellow one a variable one.

The white box is set to `200px`, the green box automatically fits it and so does the yellow one. However when you hover it the orange box expands and instead of just overflowing the yellow one (which is what I want) it pushes the yellow box and with it the root element further to right.

How can I achieve what I want?

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
}
.second {
  background: yellow;
}
.second, .first {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.first {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: width ease .5s;
}
.outer:hover .label {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="first">foo</div>
<div class="second">
<div class="label">
bar
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set max-width on your label:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
}
.second {
  background: yellow;
}
.second, .first {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.first {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: width ease .5s;
  max-width:190px;
}
.outer:hover .label {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="first">foo</div>
<div class="second">
<div class="label">
bar
</div>
</div>
</div>
```